# sqlParameter conversion

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to call the SQL statement below but get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '+@buildingIDs+' to data type int.

```
@"SELECT id, startDateTime, endDateTime 
    FROM tb_bookings 
   WHERE buildingID IN ('+@buildingIDs+') 
     AND startDateTime <= @fromDate";
```

`buildingID` is an `int` type column in the db. Will I need to pass the IDs as an array of ints?

Comment: Can you post some more code on how this is called?

Comment: This is almost exactly the same ? as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182060/sql-where-in-array-of-ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bravax's way is a bit dangerous. I'd go with the following so you don't get attacked with SQL Injections:

```
int[] buildingIDs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

/***/ @"SELECT id, startDateTime, endDateTime From tb_bookings WHERE buildingID IN (" +
      string.Join(", ", buildingIDs.Select(id => id.ToString()).ToArray())
      + ") AND startDateTime <= @fromDate";
```

Comment: To be honest, I can't see the difference in the code. We're both building a string and executing it. You've just fleshed out how you would construct the buildingIDs string.

If SQL Injection is an issue, then use a stored procedure, possibly using Marc Gravell's approach.

Comment: The difference is small but significant - Your code example implied string concatenation using a passed in string(which introduces the possibility of SQL Injection); This example passes in an integer array, essentially forcing clean data to be passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that LINQ can do this via Contains (which maps to IN). With regular TSQL, another option is to pass down the list as a CSV (etc) varchar, and use a table-valued UDF to split the varchar into pieces. This allows you to use a single TSQL query (doing an INNER JOIN to the UDF result).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to go for a stored procedure, if possilble,  and pass the lists of IDs as xml. You can get more details on this approach from **[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)**.

Answer (score -1):

It's trying to compare an int with the string value '+@buildingsIDs+'
So it tries to convert the string to convert it to an int and fails.

So do the following:

`buildingsIDs = "1, 5, 6";

@"SELECT id, startDateTime, endDateTime From tb_bookings WHERE buildingID IN (" + buildingIDs + ") AND startDateTime <= @fromDate";`