# LINQ-To-SQL ExecuteCommand with 'IN' statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
long[] conIds = GetIDs();
dc.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Deliveries SET Invoiced = NULL WHERE ID IN {0}",conIds);
```

I'd expect that to work, but the executecommand statement throws an exception stating that

> A query parameter cannot be of type int64[].

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of longs into a placeholder where a string is expected. You need to convert the array into a concatenated string with comma delimiters. Then, pass that into the command text.

Depending on where else you are using the `GetIDs` method, you could simplify your code by having that method return an array of strings. Then you can easily use `String.Join` here to convert that array to the concatenated text that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. SQL parameters must be single values.

You can make this work by converting your array to a list of comma separated values.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182060/where-in-array-of-ids) for an example.

```
command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace(
  "@conIDs", 
  string.Join(conIDs.Select(b => b.ToString()), ",")
);
```

In general, it's better to serialize your SQL and use a table valued parameter for this sort of thing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause/337817#337817) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this and I found that Linq is very particular about parameters.  I had to build the SQL statement as a string and pass that string to .ExecuteCommand() for it to work.  There was no error, just no results.  Confusing.

That said has anyone seen a good solid method of viewing what Linq is passing to Sql Server?

I've used the SQL profiler but it's a tad vague.

Comment: The DataContext.Log property lets you specify a TextWriter to log queries to. E.g. You can output it to the Console with `DataContext.Log = Console.Out`