# Add multiple parameters - string values

Tags: c#, string, sqlcommand

I have for example this sql command:

```
string strediska="0003,0005";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select code from table where stred in (@strediskac)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strediskac", strediska));
```

But result is not right. Have you any idea how I could insert more values in one "variable"?

NOW its OK! Thanks for help. My solution:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select code from table where stred in ("+ strediska +")",con);
```

Comment: This would result in select code from table where stred in ('0003,0005') and that is why you are getting it wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182060/where-in-array-of-ids

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/284240

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Note that with your current solution you opened a security issue by sql injection if 'strediska' is user input.