# Passing an "in" list via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I construct a stored procedure that will allow me to pass (for example) an `@IDList` so that I can write:

```
Select * from Foo Where ID in @IDList
```

Is this doable?

Comment: Which database are you using? Which language are you passing the list from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this answer...

[T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values/43767#43767)

Answer (score 12):

With SQL2005 and above you can send an array from code directly.

First create a custom type

```
CREATE TYPE Array AS table (Item varchar(MAX))
```

Than the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_TakeArray
    @array AS Array READONLY
AS BEGIN
    Select * from Foo Where ID in (SELECT Item FROM @array)
END
```

Then call from code passing in a DataTable as the array

```
DataTable items = new DataTable();
items.Columns.Add( "Item", typeof( string ) );

DataRow row = items.NewRow();
row.SetField<string>( "Item", <item to add> );
items.Rows.Add( row );

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "sp_TakeArray", connection );
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add( "@Array", SqlDbType.Structured );
param.Value = items;
param.TypeName = "dbo.Array";

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This is only applicable to Sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Write the individual IDs to table B, all with the same "key" (a GUID perhaps).
Then, your query against table A would include

```
where ID in (select ID from B where key = @TempKey)
```

(You might then delete the keys if you  are finished with them.  Or, timestamp them and have a sql job do it later.)

**Pros:**

- You don't send a string, which could expose you to sql injection in some circumstances.
- Depending on your other app logic, you don't have to track or write the possibilities all at once.

**Cons:**

- It could be extremely inefficient, especially under heavy loads.