# How do I use a comma separated list of values as a filter in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a basic SQL query, starting with:

```
SELECT top 20 application_id, [name], location_id FROM apps
```

Now, I would like to finish it so that it does this (written in Pseudocode)

```
if @lid > 0 then
    WHERE location_id IN (@lid)
else
    WHERE location_id is all values in location_id column
```

---

As requested, here is an example

```
application_id             name               location_id
----------------------------------------------------------
1                          Joe Blogs          33
2                          Sam Smith          234
3                          Jeremy Carr        33
```

@locid is the results given by the user, for example '33, 234'

If @lid is empty then I'd like it to output all rows for location_id with name and application_id. Otherwise, I'd like it to output all rows in relation to the provided numbers in @lid (standing for location_id.

So, if @lid is 0:

```
application_id             name               location_id
----------------------------------------------------------
1                          Joe Blogs          33
2                          Sam Smith          234
3                          Jeremy Carr        33
```

Otherwise, if @lid contains '33'

```
application_id             name               location_id
----------------------------------------------------------
1                          Joe Blogs          33
3                          Jeremy Carr        33
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and desired resultset?

Comment: Hopefully this is enough for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **Case**, which serves the purpose of an IIF or a ternary operator. Please check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

cheers

Comment: I've tried case, but with mixed results. Could you provide some sample code that I could try against my examples?

Comment: CASE WHEN MyNum < 10 THEN 'Small' ELSE 'Big' END

Answer (score 3):

If @locid is a list eg "33, 234" etc, then no solution here will work. However, I guess these were posted before your update with this information.

I assume that because you said this:

> @locid is the results given by the
>   user, for example '33, 234'

You can not expand the variable directly so that `location_in IN (33, 234)`. You are actually asking for `location_id = '33, 234'`, which will fail with a CAST conversion, because of datatype precedence.

You have to parse the list first into a table form for use in a JOIN/EXISTS construct. 
There are several options and Erland covers them all here: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: You are correct, and I have already parsed this varchar "list" so that it already checks every value, as a form of using multiple values in one select statement.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming @locid & @lid are the **same**, I'm going to use @locid...  The following would work.  I've split it up to keep it looking good on SO.

```
SELECT application_id, [name], location_id 
FROM apps
WHERE
  ( 
    @locid = 0
    OR 
    CHARINDEX
    ( 
      ',' + CAST(location_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ','
      , 
      ',' + @locid + ','
      , 
      0 
    ) > 0
  )
```

Comment: how can i trim extra spaces passed in CSVs?

Answer (score 2):

See this entry in my blog:

- [**IN with a comma separated list: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/23/in-with-a-comma-separated-list-sql-server/)

If your `@lid` is a comma-delimited list of integers, use this:

```
WITH    cd AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS first, CHARINDEX(',', @lid, 1) AS next
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  next + 1, CHARINDEX(',', @lid, next + 1)
        FROM    cd
        WHERE   next > 0
        ),
        lid AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(@lid, first, CASE next WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@lid) + 1 ELSE next END - first)AS INT) AS id
        FROM    cd
        )
SELECT  d.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    lid
        ) l
JOIN    apps a
ON      a.location_id = l.id
        AND @lid <> '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    apps a
WHERE   @lid = '0'
```

This is much more efficient than using `OR` constructs.

Comment: My aim is to return all rows in the location_id column if there is nothing in @lid, so the same kind of results as "SELECT location_id from enquiries" would produce. If there is nothing in @lid I want it to search for every location_id in the database.

Comment: Deleted my answer and gave you +1 after some benchmarks on the OR construct with some larger datasets. Never quite clicked to me how inefficient they are (only used on smaller data sets). Anyway, I think that the last query is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks. Yes, SQL Server cannot optimize OR's well. However, your query would work nice in MySQL: it would notice that @lid is not a zero and completely remove the predicate from the plan.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(LocationId, @lid) > 1
```

Comment: You should better elaborate upon your answer.

Comment: it will give you wrong results when you pass '33' it will return ids 33 and also id 3, "Brett Veenstra" answer below fixes that

Answer (score 1):

One way is to split the string on the commas, strip out the spaces and insert the values into a temporary table.  Then you can join your query against the temp table.

This is a T-SQL code snippet that splits a comma-separated list and inserts the members into a temporary table.  Once you've populated the table you can join against it.

```
-- This bit splits up a comma separated list of key columns
-- and inserts them in order into a table. 
--
if object_id ('tempdb..#KeyCols') is not null
    drop table #KeyCols

create table #KeyCols (
      ,KeyCol           nvarchar (100)
)

set @comma_pos = 0
set @len = len(@KeyCols)
while @len > 0 begin
    set @comma_pos = charindex(',', @KeyCols)
    if @comma_pos = 0 begin
        set @KeyCol = @KeyCols
        set @KeyCols = ''
    end else begin
        set @KeyCol = left (@KeyCols, @comma_pos - 1)
        set @KeyCols = substring(@KeyCols, 
                                 @comma_pos + 1, 
                                 len (@KeyCols) - @comma_pos)
    end
    insert #KeyCols (KeyCol)
    values (@KeyCol)
    set @len = len (@KeyCols)
end
```

Comment: +1, a useful technique.  Any reason to not go with an in-memory temp table only?

Comment: Not particularly - if I recall correctly the sproc that originally came from stated life on SQL Server 2000.  You could use a table variable just as easily on modern versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the ternary operator for this:

```
SELECT top 20 application_id, [name], location_id
FROM apps
WHERE (@lid > 0 AND location_id IN (@lid)) OR @lid <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking different questions here. This is the answer to your original question (about the ternary operator, but as you can see, you don't need anything like a ternary operator for this):

```
SELECT top 20 application_id, [name], location_id 
FROM apps
WHERE @lid = 0 OR location_id IN (@lid)
```

But that was before we knew that @lid was a varchar and could contain different comma separated values.

Well, this (about the csv) is another question which has been asked here before:

[Passing an "in" list via stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617706/passing-an-in-list-via-stored-procedure)
[T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: @gbn: this has nothing to do with the question at hand, which is about a ternary operator (which is also not what's needed here, but that's again another discution ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick for you.

DECLARE @lid SMALLINT

SET @lid = 0

SELECT top 20 application_id, [name], location_id

FROM apps

WHERE ((@lid > 0 AND location_id = @lid)

```
  OR (@lid = 0 AND location_id > @lid))
```

If @lid = 0 then it will return ALL rows.
IF @lid has a particular value, only the row for that @lid value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not exactly a best practice to use 1=1, it does the trick here.

```
SELECT top 20 application_id, [name], location_id FROM apps
WHERE
  (@lid > 0 and @lid = location_id)
or
  (isnull(@lid, 0) <= 0 and 1=1)
```