# SQL Server IN with multiple values as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP as below (example only) and want to filter the City based on values passed in as a parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN (@cities_as_a_parameter);
```

In my C# code, I have the below

```
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MY_SPNAME";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cities_as_a_parameter", "'Paris','London', 'xxx', 'yyyy'");
```

My question is how to pass multiple values to the SP parameter @cities_as_a_parameter ? Above code does not work and want to know what is the correct way of doing this.

What is the best way to do this ?

OR is there any other way to do this (without using multiple where conditions)?

Comment: You can't pass multiple values via a single parameter.  You either need multiple parameters or else your sproc needs to accept the input as a single string and then it must split it into multiple values.

Comment: Look at one of those duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617706/passing-an-in-list-via-stored-procedure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure. A real analysis of this topic is done on an excellent article about this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @SQL     VARCHAR(3000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * 
            FROM Customers
            WHERE City IN (' + @cities_as_a_parameter +')';
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Just make sure you properly build your string.

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injection, insanely slow as the list grows and input is restricted in size. Works, but it's the worst possible method, unfortunately.

Comment: yah, the only method i can think :P, but you can improve it, need your inputs.

Comment: Look at my comment in the question for some alternatives. Too long and complex to describe myself :D, but there are good links there.

Answer (score -1):

put the parameter after your stored proc name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[your_sp_name](@cities_as_a_parameter navarchar(10))

SELECT * FROM Customers
```

WHERE City IN (@cities_as_a_parameter);