# how to use 'in' Operator in ,SQL Queries Stored Procedures,passing Multiple Values in a single parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

how to add Multiple values for a single parameter while using 'in' Operator in  SQL Server
 'Stored Procedure'

for example:

```
create procedure ProcEmployee ( @DeptID int )
as
begin
select* from employee where **DeptID in (@DeptID)**
end
```

from the above example, i need to pass multiple values for the parameter '@DeptID'