# Selection with a IN statement from a varchar value

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, performance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

I have a stored procedure who have to select values with a filter system.
Imagine a Table

```
ColA | ColB | ColC |

'A'    12     1
'B'    13     2
'C'    14     3
```

I need to give to stored procedure a list of ColC values for those a want the values, example (1,3)
will give me 'A' and 'C'.

I know it is possible to do a IN statement like :

```
Select *
from Table
where ColC in (1,3)
```

But how make this dynamic? a solution will be to construct the sql command in a Varchar variable like

```
SET @MyList ='(1,3)'
SET @SQL = '
     Select *
    from Table
    where ColC in ' + @MyList 

And then execute @SQL
```

But is it the best way? To make dynamic command like this is not too heavy?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I wouldn't trust this user input without extra validation (the list of IDs).

Comment: Sql server 2008 sorry I edit tags

Comment: dupped: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values

Comment: Have a look at this (infamous) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: @Rodrigo: agree It's asked daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of different options on how to [pass arrays to stored procedures](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm), however, the common practice is building the query like you have shown, hence I think it's the best solution here.

EDIT: [Arrays in SQL 2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) still shows building a query as the first approach.

Comment: That link is way out of date. And the common practice of string buidling isn't the best way. http://stackoverflow.com/q/43249/27535

Comment: thanks, however, it is still applicable. if you don't think so, let's see you suggest a more efficient approach.

Comment: The link I added matches your new link. This is the reference source. I've voted to close because of this

Comment: Thanks a lot Bad Display Name, Method 2 of your link really help me..