# Passing multiple rows of data to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have a list of objects (created from several text files) in C#.net that I need to store in a SQL2005 database file.  Unfortunately, Table-Valued Parameters began with SQL2008 so they won't help. I found from MSDN that one method is to "Bundle multiple data values into delimited strings or XML documents and then pass those text values to a procedure or statement" but I am rather new to stored procedures and need more help than that.  I know I could create a stored procedure to create one record then loop through my list and add them, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.  Thanks.

```
Input file example (Other files contain pricing and availability):
Matnr   ShortDescription    LongDescription ManufPartNo Manufacturer    ManufacturerGlobalDescr GTIN    ProdFamilyID    ProdFamily  ProdClassID ProdClass   ProdSubClassID  ProdSubClass    ArticleCreationDate CNETavailable   CNETid  ListPrice   Weight  Length  Width   Heigth  NoReturn    MayRequireAuthorization EndUserInformation  FreightPolicyException
10000000    A&D ENGINEERING SMALL ADULT CUFF FOR UA-767PBT  UA-279  A&D ENGINEERING A&D ENG 093764011542    GENERAL General TDINTERNL   TD Internal TDINTERNL   TD Internal 2012-05-13 12:18:43 N       18.000  .350                N   N   N   N
10000001    A&D ENGINEERING MEDIUM ADULT CUFF FOR UA-767PBT UA-280  A&D ENGINEERING A&D ENG 093764046070    GENERAL General TDINTERNL   TD Internal TDINTERNL   TD Internal 2012-05-13 12:18:43 N       18.000  .450                N   N   N   N
```

Some DataBase File fields:

```
EffectiveDate           varchar(50)
MfgName                 varchar(500)
MfgPartNbr              varchar(500)
Cost                    varchar(200)
QtyOnHand               varchar(200)
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to do and what does your object(s) look like?

Comment: My objects consist of 11 string properties corresponding to the fields in the database.  So far the only thing I've tried is to search for a direction.

Comment: Why not store them as separate records, and tie them together with a relationship from another table?

Comment: Why can't you use a stored procedure with a parameters for each of the  corresponding fields in the database? Then pass each string into each parameter?

Comment: @Patrick the problem if he's passing 1000 rows, he has to call a single stored procedure with the 1 explicit parameters 1000 times. This is usually not going to perform very well as 1000 separate procedure calls.

Comment: @BrianMains - Not sure I follow.  Store them where and how?  The data I'm starting with in is txt files and I've pulled the info I need into a list of objects.

Comment: Can you show an example of a couple of lines from your text file, and the table where you want to store them?

Comment: See the [first answer to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values) - it lists a ton of ways to do this, with pros and cons and extensive discussion - highly recommended!

Comment: Or see [this MSDN blog post by Jon Galloway for a sample of how to use XML to solve your problem](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

Comment: @DanNorton Ignore my post; I was confused and my post is off-topic.

Comment: @BrianMains you can delete your own comments. I'll delete this one in a few minutes, for example. :-)

Comment: I usually use SqlBulkCopy when "importing" text files into SQL Server from C#.  Could this be used or am I missing something?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, I realized as I was posting that I was probably missing something obvious. That's the problem with posting late at night, on little sleep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split multiple values from a single string quite easily. Say you can bundle the string like this, using a comma to separate "columns", and a semi-colon to separate "rows":

```
foo, 20120101, 26; bar, 20120612, 32
```

(This assumes that colons and semi-colons can't appear naturally in the data; if they can, you'll need to choose other delimiters.)

You can build a split routine like this, which includes an output column that allows you to determine the order the value appeared in the original string:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

Then you can query it like this (for simplicity and illustration I'm only handling 3 properties but you can extrapolate this for 11 or n):

```sql
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX); -- a parameter to your stored procedure

SET @x = N'foo, 20120101, 26; bar, 20120612, 32';

;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT ID = s.Number, InnerID = y.Number, y.Item 
    -- parameter and "row" delimiter here:
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@x, ';') AS s
    -- output and "column" delimiter here:
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.Item, ',') AS y
)
SELECT 
    prop1 = x.Item, 
    prop2 = x2.Item, 
    prop3 = x3.Item
FROM x 
INNER JOIN x AS x2 
ON x.InnerID = x2.InnerID - 1
AND x.ID = x2.ID
INNER JOIN x AS x3
ON x2.InnerID = x3.InnerID - 1
AND x2.ID = x3.ID
WHERE x.InnerID = 1
ORDER BY x.ID;
```

Results:

```
prop1   prop2     prop3
------  --------  -------
foo     20120101  26
bar     20120612  32
```

Comment: This might be serviceable depending on the data size and contents, and +1 to Aaron for a fully-developed and tested answer. But see my answer for some caveats on the implementation here as well as an alternative strategy. Specifically, T-SQL Split UDFs can be slow, and the `dbo.SplitStrings` UDF shown here is not suitable for more complex data (say, where values can contain the delimiter). Though, the caveat to the caveat is that you can always choose less common delimiters to make problems less likely.

Comment: @DominicP I did make a disclaimer within the answer about choosing delimiters wisely.

Comment: Right, I should have been more clear. What I was talking about was just the theoretical point that if the data is unconstrained delimiter choice can actually become a rather tricky problem that I wanted to draw a little more attention to. In practice, you often can make reasonable assumptions about the input data, making a Split function feasible-- which is why I upvoted your answer. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

We use XML data types like this...

```
declare @contentXML xml
set @contentXML=convert(xml,N'<ROOT><V a="124694"/><V a="124699"/><V a="124701"/></ROOT>')

SELECT  content_id,
  FROM  dbo.table c WITH (nolock) 
  JOIN @contentXML.nodes('/ROOT/V') AS R ( v ) ON c.content_id = R.v.value('@a', 'INT')
```

Here is what it would look like if calling a stored procedure...

```
DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand("MyStroredProcedure);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "dataPubXML", DbType.Xml, dataPublicationXml);

CREATE PROC dbo.usp_get_object_content
(
    @contentXML XML
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT  content_id,
      FROM    dbo.tblIVContent c WITH (nolock) 
      JOIN @contentXML.nodes('/ROOT/V') AS R ( v ) ON c.content_id = R.v.value('@a', 'INT')

 END
```

SQL Server does not parse XML very quickly so the use of the SplitStrings function might be more performant.  Just wanted to provide an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few options, but as I was typing one of them (the Split option) was posted by Mr. @Bertrand above. The only problem with it is that SQL [just isn't that good at string manipulation](http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/comparing-simple-efficiencies-tsql-udf-sqclr-udf-splitting-strings/).

So, another option would be to use a #Temp table that your sproc assumes will be present. Build dynamic SQL to the following effect:

Start a transaction, `CREATE TABLE #InsertData` with the shape you need, then loop over the data you are going to insert, using `INSERT INTO #InsertData SELECT <values> UNION ALL SELECT <values>....`

There are some limitations to this approach, one of which is that as the data set becomes very large you may need to split the INSERTs into batches. (I don't recall the specific error I got when I learned this myself, but for very long lists of values I have had SQL complain.) The solution, though, is simple: just generate a series of INSERTs with a smaller number of rows each. For instance, you might do 10 `INSERT SELECTs` with 1000 `UNION ALLs` each instead of 1 `INSERT SELECT` with 10000 `UNION ALLs`. You can still pass the entire batch as a part of a single command.

The advantage of this (despite its various disadvantages-- the use of temporary tables, long command strings, etc) is that it offloads all the string processing to the much more efficient C# side of the equation and doesn't require an additional persistent database object (the Split function; though, again, who doesn't need one of these sometimes)?

If you DO go with a Split() function, I'd encourage you to offload this to a SQLCLR function, and NOT a T-SQL UDF (for the performance reasons illustrated by the link above).

Finally, whatever method you choose, note that you'll have more problems if your data can include strings that contain the delimiter (for instance, In Aaron's answer you run into problems if the data is:

```
'I pity the foo!', 20120101, 26; 'bar, I say, bar!', 20120612, 32
```

Again, because C# is better at string handling than T-SQL, you'll be better off without using a T-SQL UDF to handle this.

**Edit**

Please note the following additional point to think about for the dynamic INSERT option.

You need to decide whether any input here is potentially dangerous input and would need to be cleaned before use. You cannot easily parameterize this data, so this is a significant one. In the place I used this strategy, I already had strong guarantees about the type of the data (in particular, I have used it for seeding a table with a list of integer IDs to process, so I was iterating over integers and not arbitrary, untrusted strings). If you don't have similar assurances, be aware of the dangers of SQL injection.