# Stored procedure that accepts multiple primary key and get the values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

```
USE [dbindia]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 alter proc [procedurename]        
 @srchtxt varchar(50),        
 @status varchar(50),
 @id int        
as        
 select a.listtitle as productname,a.listdesc as description,buyingprice as Price,b.catname as [Primary Category],c.catname as [Secondary Category],d.catname as      [Tritary Category],e.catname as [Quartery Category],
a.balanceqty as [Current Stock],  
'http://ghsindia.biz/image/product/'+a.imgname as Image1,  
'http://ghsindia.biz/image/product/'+a.imgname2 as Image2,  
'http://ghsindia.biz/image/product/'+a.imgname3 as Image3,  
'http://ghsindia.biz/image/product/'+a.imgname4 as Image4,  
'http://ghsindia.biz/image/product/'+a.imgname5 as Image5 from
tbllisting a inner join tblcategory b on a.catid=b.catid   
 left outer join tblSeccategory c on a.catid2=c.Seccatid  
 left outer join tbltricategory d on a.catid3=d.tricatid  
 left outer join tblquarcategory e on a.catid4=e.quarcatid  
 where a.blockstatus=@status and a.listtitle like '%'+@srchtxt+'%' and a.bstatus=1
 **and a.listid in (@id)** order by a.listtitle
```

This is my stored procedure. I want to get all the values where `a.listid` can be one or more but how will write in this if values of id is like (1,2,3)

Comment: You should find hits if you search this site with terms like "IN Clause" and "parameter".

Comment: But how to pass multiple id values from code behind c#

Comment: If you look at the question linked as a duplicate, *lots* of options are given for how to do this. E.g. TVPs if available.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me on this.