# SQL - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to Int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am passing `varchar` values to a SQL function.

But I get this error:

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '201,505,59,43,2202' to data type int.*

Sample Code :

```
Declare @Fault Varchar(Max) = '201,505,59,43,2202'

Select * 
From EventMsg 
Where Event IN (Convert(Int, @Fault))
```

I tried both `CAST` & `CONVERT` functions...but same error.

Comment: The error message is fully comnprehensible. This string is not intepretable as an integer. How do you want it to get interpreted?

Comment: A single string value containing digits and commas is *not* the same as a sequence of *multiple* values. SQL Server does *not* look inside the single value and decide to split it into *multiple* values.

Comment: Then is there any way to do it ? i want to pass all values at once in function.

Comment: SQL Server has *one* data type that actually *supports* multiple values natively. It's called... a table. So, if possible, switch to passing multiple values as a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing a comma separated list of integer values as a string and wanting to use each value then you will need to write a function similar to String.Split in the .NET world.

There are a ton of answers on Stack Overflow about this here are some

- [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)
- [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)
- ... etc

Answer (score 0):

Just another way is to declare table variable:

```
DECLARE @errorCodes AS TABLE (
    err INT
)
INSERT INTO @errorCodes (err) VALUES (1), (2), (3)

Select * From EventMsg Where Event IN (SELECT err FROM @errorCodes)
```