# T-SQL: pass an array of ids to a stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to send and array of parameters to a stored procedure

```
SELECT [id_Curso] AS IDCurso
  ,[Cod_Estabelecimento] AS CodEstabelecimento
  ,[Des_Estabelecimento] AS DesEstabelecimento
  ,[Cod_Curso] AS CodCurso
  ,[Des_Curso] AS DescCurso
  ,[Cod_Grau] AS CodGrau
  ,[Des_Grau] AS DescGrau
  ,[Cod_Area_Educacao] AS CodAreaEducacao
  FROM [BEP_DEV].[dbo].[Curso]
  where [Cod_Area_Educacao] in @List

DECLARE @List VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @List = '(1,2,3,4)';

SELECT [id_Curso] AS IDCurso
  ,[Cod_Estabelecimento] AS CodEstabelecimento
  ,[Des_Estabelecimento] AS DesEstabelecimento
  ,[Cod_Curso] AS CodCurso
  ,[Des_Curso] AS DescCurso
  ,[Cod_Grau] AS CodGrau
  ,[Des_Grau] AS DescGrau
  ,[Cod_Area_Educacao] AS CodAreaEducacao
  FROM [BEP_DEV].[dbo].[Curso]
where [Cod_Area_Educacao] in (1,2,3,4)
```

How can I transform the first case in something like the 2nd one (which works.)?

I tried also with xml but also can't make it work.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: check the first link on right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values?rq=1

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of possibilities for that, but given the you're on SQL 2008 the number one choice would be to use the new table valued parameters, in which you can send a whole table to a query or stored procedure in a single go (in your case, a table with a single column with an arbitrary number of IDs).

First create a table type in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE idTable AS TABLE (id INT)
```

Then just declare your procedure with a parameter of that type, and use it like any other table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectList (@IDs idTable READONLY) AS
SELECT * FROM sometable
INNER JOIN @IDs AS idTable ON idTable.id=sometable.id
```

There is a great article that discusses this and other methods in detail for doing what you need http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a udf that parses the string and inserts the values into a table (containing one int column in your case), and then join your Curso table on the table resulting from calling the udf on your CSV string.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass it as xml. Its easy and very performant. Here is a good post with the details. https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/01/05/using-xml-to-pass-lists-as-parameters-in-sql-server/