# How can I found Easy method for this in C# Windows base Application

Tags: c#, windows, multiple-select-query

[Here i have 10 checkbox, now I want that if my client select any of this and any number of checkbox selected then Report will Generate and in this coding also I want to use StoredProcedure, now if I go with coding individualy for all Possibilities I have to write 99 StoredProcedure and 99 times Coding, So is there any easy Possible way for this Problem..?? ]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your issue in more detail? As it stands, it's very unclear what's being asked.

Comment: Creating a single SP and passing the checkbox value as a parameter?

Comment: Yaa, exactly Samar, in brief if I select checkbox of H.T., Unit and OEM then also result will get and IF I select Stor H.T., Unit and Assembly then also result will get this both things i want in single Query and single coding..... and same for the all other possibilities

Comment: Adrian Wragg, I am very sorry, I know, I can't explain it properly because of Language bearer

Comment: Code! Show us some code! We all understand this universal language here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which database are you using? `SQL Server 2008` or higher? If yes then the answer by @user3353613 will be useful. If not then you can pass `comma/pipe(|)` separated checkbox values to a single parameter to your stored procedure and then you can split the values inside the stored procedure to get what you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try Table-Valued parameter. Or you might get some ideas from this post. [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values/43767#43767)