# How to execute a SP using a dynamic range in tsql

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have this tsql/sp...

```
declare @IdRange NVARCHAR(255)

SET @IdRange = '1,2,4'

select 
    FeatureName
FROM
    Feature F
    JOIN GroupFeature GF ON GF.FeatureId = F.FeatureId 
WHERE 
    GroupId IN ( @IdRange)
```

The value for @IdRange can vary.

This, when executed will fail.

I could use dynamic SQL and execute it all as string but I just want to explore if there is an alternative?

I have now tried this:

```
declare @IdRange NVARCHAR(255)

SET @IdRange = '1,2,4'
select 
    FeatureName
FROM
    Feature F
    JOIN GroupFeature GF ON GF.FeatureId = F.FeatureId 
WHERE 
    CHARINDEX(',' + GroupId + ',', ',' + @IdRange + ',') <> 0
```

and get this:

```
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
WHERE
    CHARINDEX(',' + cast(GroupId as varchar) + ',', ',' + @IdRange + ',') <> 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my question to show my latest attempt based on your suggestion. It is possible that I am not understanding what you are suggestion though :)

Comment: lol, I just realised myself!  This is what happens when you are stuck in traffic for 2 hours going into work!. Thanks it worked!

Comment: Hi, just realized that this reorders my results by GroupId.  So in my example where the args are 1.2.4 (and I add the GroupId onto the select bit) it returns correctly. If I change the args to 1.4.2 it rearranges it as 1.2.4. Is there a way I can stop this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For deeper study and understanding:
I think that this [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values) responds to your question the best.

As for short answer:
The reason is, that *IN* operator corresponds to a set, it doesnt work for a string...

Alternatives for you:

```
WHERE ','+@IdRange+',' like + '%,'+GroupId+',%'
```

or
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + GroupId + ',', ',' + @IdRange + ',') > 0
this adds leading and ending comma to the IdRange string and then uses the like operator to search for records. The pros: Simple to write and understand, Cons: Performance for big datasets and unable to use any kind of index

I wont talk about changeing the type of input to the SP (ie a table variable or temporal table), another alternative,especially if the Feature table contains a lot of records would be to:
1) parse the @IdRange into a temp table
2) utilize join/intersect

to split, read this [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

and then just select from Feature table joining on the temp table

Have a nice day

Comment: HI, thanks for your insight. Much appreciated. I need to look into all that you said and wil lreport back. Thanks