# Error converting data type varchar to bigint - IN clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a `DELETE` statement where I'll delete some items from a table based on a list of ids, using the `IN` clause:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (@ids)
```

Using a `SqlCommand`, I'm doing the following to generate the `IN` parameter:

```
public void DeleteItemsByIds(int[] ids) {

    Parameters["ids"] = string.Join(", ", ids);
    ExecuteNonQuery(deleteStatement, Parameters);
}
```

Then I'm getting an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Someone know how could I solve it?

Thank you all!

Comment: Well, the `IN` expects a **list of (presumably) `BIGINT`** values, while what you're providing is really just **a single string** ..... For SQL Server **2008** and newer, check out **table-valued parameters** to pass multiple values to a SQL statement

Comment: Construct the entire SQL statement as text, not just the inclusion set, and that should work.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: that is **horrible** advice as it opens up the possibility of **SQL injection** attacks... seriously - don't do this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values) SO answer. it is tailored on stored procedures but the proposed solutions are suitable for your situation. moreover you may get some hint pushing you to a stored procedure instead of a standalone (dynamic sql?) delete statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` expects a list of things whose types on the left and right side are compatible.  Clearly the left side of the `in` is numeric and the right side is a string.  And, you cannot convert the string to a number, because it is a comma-delimited list.

The fast and dirty solution is to simply use `like`:

```
DELETE
    FROM table
    WHERE ',' + @ids + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(id as VARCHAR(255)) + ',%';
```

However, this is suboptimal in terms of performance, because it cannot make use of an index on `id`.  Better solutions requiring knowing more about the application that is using the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**this will definitely help you**

```
select * from tblusers where userid in(select value from String_Split('1,2,3,4',','))
```

String_Split is an inbuilt SQL function