# Declare var for IN statement in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have that sql code

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I would like to have that expression

```
DECLARE @allNeededIds ??? = (1,2,3,4,5,6)

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN @allNeededIds
```

Could I declare something like this in SQL or should I use table, how will code looks then? I use MS Sql Server

Comment: Does `id` is numeric field?

Comment: I *was* going to flag this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function, but it appears to be hideously out-of-date.  Still, I expect there is a more-up-to-date duplicate out there.

Comment: @MaciejLos: For example it could be INT, I just need know how code should look

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables here's a pretty up-to date answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43767/119477

Comment: @ConradFrix - yeah, but that's just a bunch of links, yuck

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support arrays or lists, etc.  You either have to fudge it *(Dynamic SQL, storing values in string lists then using table-valued-functions to split the string up, etc)* or use tables directly *(including table variables, temporary tables, permanent tables, etc)*

Comment: @MatBailie - `xml` ought to be somewhere in your list also. At least it's *designed* for holding multiple values, unlike strings, and there are built in functions that take in XML and give you back *sets*, unlike strings.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Not used SQL Server in a long time, forgot about XML support :)  Much better that `split_list()` udf's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a table-variable:

```
DECLARE @allNeededIds table(id int not null)
insert into @allNeededIds (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (select id from @allNeededIds)
```

If you wanted to pass this set of values into this code from an outside source (e.g. calling this code in a stored procedure or running it from another language), you should look at [Table-Valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - I couldn't tell you. It may be because it's slightly closer to the OPs proposed structure (having the explicit variable)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Dynamic SQL to do this.

```
DECLARE @MyTSQLStatement nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @allNeededIds nvarchar(max) 
SET @allNeededIds =  '(1,2,3,4,5,6)'

SET @MyTSQLStatement = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN ' + @allNeededIds

EXEC sp_executesql @MyTSQLStatement
```

Comment: I don't think it's the case for Dynamic SQL.

Comment: How else does it allow for one variable to constitute the entirety of the IN clause, as specified by the OP?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I think implementing the logic that will generate the 1 through 6 values in a `SELECT`, similar to my answer would be better than generating and executing a dynamic SQL, even if the outcome will be the same.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I think it's a better technique too, but the OP explicitly wants to assign a comma separated list to one variable (I assume for an input parameter to a procedure).  If you want to turn that into a  sub-select as in your answer, we probably should show him how to parse out the string to extract the values for inserting into the temp table too.

Comment: The OP seemed to be quite open about what approach they were taking so I'd rather point them towards e.g. table-valued parameters (something *designed* for multiple values) rather than suggesting a string parameter and then having to pull it apart.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I can be on board with that.  I guess I took his pseudocode a little too literal as a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

in which scenario `SELECT id FROM table2` would return the values 1 through 6.

Of course, if the inner `SELECT` will return more values than the ones you need, you will need to adjust the query by using an additional `WHERE` clause to filter just the values you need.

Comment: If you downvoted my answer please post a comment, I'm really curious what is wrong with my solution and what could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

First create a Split function which will take a comma separated string as input and return a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].Split(@input AS Varchar(4000) )
RETURNS
      @Result TABLE(Value BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)
      DECLARE @ind Int
      IF(@input is not null)
      BEGIN
            SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            WHILE @ind > 0
            BEGIN
                  SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                  SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                  INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
                  SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            END
            SET @str = @input
            INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
      END
      RETURN
END
```

Second, do this to get result:

```
DECLARE @allNeededIds as varchar(max)
set @allNeededIds = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
select value into temp from Split(@allNeededIds)
```

Final query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (select value in temp)
```

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.split(@allNeededIds)`