# How to save a dictionary into a database with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, relational-database

I have been using following way to save dictionaries into the database:

1. Convert the dictionary to XML.
2. Pass this XML to a SP(Stored Procedure).
3. In the SP use:

   ```
   Select 
       Key1,                   
       Value1
   into #TempTable                                      
   FROM OPENXML(@handle, '//ValueSet/Values', 1)
   WITH 
   (                                  
     key1 VARCHAR(MAX),     
     value1 varchar(100)  
   )
   ```
4. Done.

Is there a way to save dictionaries to a database without converting it to XML?

Comment: just save the key and the values into the corresponding columns in a table in the database. What is in the dictionary?

Comment: Key- string and Value - string

Comment: what about creating a table with a key and value column ?

Comment: @NedStoyanov Will it be efficient if i loop Dictionary and in Sp i pass parameter for each "Key-Value Pair"?

Comment: you can pass a list of all the keys and values to the SP, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43767/1239433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It depends whether...

- **You want the data to be stored:** The fastest way (both implementation and performance) to do that is by binary serialization ([Protocol buffers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) for example). However the data is not readable with a select and every application who needs to read the data must use the same serialization (if it exists in the same technology/language). From my point of view, it breaks the **purpose of storing in a SQL database**.
- **You want the data to be readable by humans:** XML is an option while not so fast and a little bit difficult to read and still it is not query-able. However, it is quite fast to implement. You can also dump the result to a file and it's still readable. Moreover, you can share the data with other applications as XML is a widespread format.
- **You want the data to be query-able.** Depending on the way you go, it could be not so easy to implement. You would need two tables (one for keys and one for values). Then you could write either your own custom mapping code to map columns to properties or you could use frameworks for mapping objects to tables like [Entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate).

While Entity or NHibernate may appear a bit huge swiss knife for a small problem, it's always interesting to built some expertise in it, as the inner concepts are re-usable and it can really speed up development once you got a working setup.

Answer (score 4):

`Serialize` the Dictionary, and store the binary data.

Then De-Serialize your data back into `Dictionary`.

[Tutorial1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C) [Tutorial2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list)

Answer (score -2):

Loop through the dictionary using a foreach statement.

Comment: Will it be efficient? I don't think so.