# All lines from the Dictionary to a single table on the DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary

This questions had been posted several times ([1](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/805736/How-do-I-save-Dictionary-in-csharp),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078491/how-to-save-a-dictionary-into-a-database-with-c),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052318/storing-a-dictionarystring-string-in-the-database),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922388/storing-a-dictionaryint-string-or-keyvaluepair-in-a-database)), but I did not find one that would apply to my case.

I have a Dictionary with the structure:

```
public Dictionary<Int32, PhaseMag> Data;
```

Where PhaseMag:

```
public struct PhaseMag
{
    public Single Magnitude;
    public Single Phase;
}
```

Each Key value will contain two 2 values (Mag. and Phase). If you prefer to see [an image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98UpTa2n4XbRFZHMmdzOXhUams/view?usp=sharing).

- I need to store all the content of this Dictionary in a unique Table in the DB (Microsoft SQL). Each line of the Dictionary should become one line of my DB Table. My final table will contain 3 fields, 1) Key 2) Mag and 3) Phase. For example, if I have 30 Keys, my table will contain 30 lines, one for each key.

---

My ideas:

- Create a foreach loop based on each Key and create an insert into to the DB (one for Key->Mag and other for Key->Phase). But I don't think that this will be the best approach, especially, because my dictionary contains several thousand of lines.

So, what should be my approach to do this? I simply need to save my Dictionary into the DB, which each line of the Dic. will be one line from the DB.

Comment: Create a `DataTable` from your `Dictionary` and pass it to a stored procedure in your sql server as a table valued parameter.

Comment: Loop the dictionary populating a DataTable then send it to the server as a bulk operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row

Comment: Yes... I was trying to do this without populating a DataTable but I think that this is the best approach! Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use pure System.Data.SqlClient or something like Entity Framework? If you want to use pure System.Data.SqlClient API you can increase efficiency with BULK INSERT https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you're using SQL Server, here're two of many options you have:

1. Bulk insert, it's recommended.

   ```
   public void BulkWrite(Dictionary<Int32, PhaseMag> data)
   {
       var dataTable = new DataTable();
       dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(int), ColumnName = "Key" });
       dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(Single), ColumnName = "Magnitude" });
       dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(Single), ColumnName = "Phase" });

       foreach (var x in data)
       {
           var r = dataTable.NewRow();
           dataTable.Rows.Add(r);
           r[0] = x.Key;
           r[1] = x.Value.Magnitude;
           r[2] = x.Value.Phase;
       }


       using (var conn = new SqlConnection("conneciton string"))
       {
           conn.Open();
           using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
           {
               bulkCopy.BatchSize = 4000;
               bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "YorTableName";
               bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Multiple inline query, executed as batch. As all your data are number, so low risk of SQL injection even using inline query.

   ```
   public void InlineQueryWrite(Dictionary<Int32, PhaseMag> data)
   {
       using (var conn = new SqlConnection("conneciton string"))
       {
           conn.Open();

           foreach (var bulk in data.Select((d, i) => new {d, i}).GroupBy(x => x.i % 10))
           {
               var sb = new StringBuilder();
               foreach (var x in bulk)
               {
                   sb.AppendFormat("Insert Into Your_Table (Key, Magnitude, Phase) Values ({0},{1},{2});", x.d.Key, x.d.Value.Magnitude, x.d.Value.Phase);
               }

               using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
               {
                   command.CommandText = sb.ToString();
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
           }

       }
   }
   ```

I haven't ran/tested through the code, but they should work.

Comment: I tested the "Bulk insert" and it works perfectly for my case. Thank you.