# Put quotes around each word in comma separated sql string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string like this:

```
'one, two, three'
```

How can I get it to look like this:

```
'one','two','three'
```

so I can use it in an IN clause?

Comment: Use [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx). Btw. you can't use strings in in-clause, you'll need also to create dynamic SQL then.

Comment: @JamesZ - I am not sure what you m mean by I can't use strings in in-clause.  I have done something like this before:  select * from table where column in ('one','two','three') and it works fine

Comment: You can do in clause that way, but you cannot use strings that have that in it. It will only look for that specific value, row with value `'one','two','three'`, not the 3 separate values

Comment: If you don't want to use dynamic sql you can convert the string to XML and then parse the XML into a table to join to.  This won't work if you have non-valid XML characters in your input.

Comment: If you're using stored procedures, you should actually use table valued parameters instead of passing comma separated strings

Comment: Be VERY careful here. This is highly likely to be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: You may find some useful information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43767/92546).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the REPLACE method. Replace comma with the required string

```
DECLARE @TestData AS VARCHAR (200) = '''one, two, three''';
DECLARE @ReplacedData AS VARCHAR (200) = '';
SELECT @ReplacedData = REPLACE(@TestData, ', ', ''',''')
```

If you want to use the `@TestData` in the `IN`, you need to use the dynamic query like below:

```
DECLARE @SqlTest AS VARCHAR (MAX) = '';
SET @SqlTest = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE ColumnValue IN (' + @ReplacedData + ')'
EXEC (@SqlTest)
```

Comment: I tried this, but my data just looks like this in the column:  one, two, three.  It does not have the back ticks, so it still produced the same string

Comment: I updated my post, it must have put it like that when editing.  It just has single quotes in the original string

Comment: I noticed you put ' ' 'one,two,three' ' ', but  when if my string just is 'one,two,three'

Comment: you have to remove the parentheses sp_executesql @SqlTest

Comment: @Arulkumar - This string '''one, two, three''' seems to work fine, but my string only has one quote surrounding the whole thing

Comment: Ok, correct me if I am wrong, but do I need the 3 quotes because that is what is used as a pattern to replace it with one quote? does that make sense

Comment: If you want to retain a `'` in the string you need to use two single quotes, it is like escaping character.

Comment: `DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(100) = 'one, two, three'; SELECT @A;
DECLARE @B AS VARCHAR(100) = '''one, two, three'''; SELECT @B;` In more detail if I want to retain the `'` I use a escape character

Comment: @dejan87 I'm not replacing comma, replacing comma to quotes around the comma. From `, ` to `','`