# easy way to query without putting everything in quotation marks

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I query in MySql without putting all inserts in quotations? (I have a big list and it would take to much time to quote and unquote every word)

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM names 
WHERE names.first IN ("joe", "tom", "vincent")
```

Comment: Is the list in a table? If so, you could do something like:
WHERE names.first IN (SELECT fname FROM wanted_names_table)

Comment: Unfortunately not... It is a list from excel.

Comment: Is this list somehow separated e.g. `joe,tom,vincent`?

Comment: Yes, it is comma separated!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145203/put-quotes-around-each-word-in-comma-separated-sql-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the list is comma separated, simply use the 'find and replace' feature to find all commas and replace them with `","`

The result should be `joe","tom","vincent","` which you can simply copy into mysql. 
All you then have to do is edit the start and end of the string

Comment: This does sort my problem. However, I was wondering if there is a mysql solution!

Comment: Use replace function in MYSQL.