# Pass TABLE as parameter without creating TYPE

Tags: sql-server

I know it is possible to create a stored procedure and pass a TABLE as parameter by doing the following:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @ids MyTableType READONLY
AS
...
```

I don't want to create a TYPE as above, because I was told to not create type dependencies in the database. So I want to do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @ids TABLE (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
```

But for some reason I get error highlights. Am I doing something wrong in the syntax? Or is this not possible to do?

Comment: This is not directly your answer, but this post goes over lots of ways to pass lists to a stored procedure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamXifaras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to declare a table type inline like you're trying to do. The first line in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) on table-valued parameters says:

> Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types.

Comment: This sounds promising, but the link is broken. Could you please edit it? Thank you!

Comment: Fixed, @MariFaleiros. Sorry about that!