# How do I declare array of integers in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I use SQL Server 2012.

I have this int[] array:

```
int[] arr = [1,23,4,3];
```

`arr` variable I sent as parameter to stored procedure.

How do I declare this variable? How do I declare array of integers in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: Stored procedure code is **highly** vendor-specific - therefore please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have any "array" type - if you need multiple values of something, there's really only one construct : a **table**.

If you need to pass multiple values to a stored procedure, you should check out **table-valued parameters** (TVP). Those allow you to send in a "table variable" full of values.

Same applies inside your stored procedure - if you need to handle multiple values, use a table variable (`@MyTable`) or a "regular" temporary table (`#MyTempTable`)

Comment: Can I use TVP inside query to filter data?

SELECT *
FROM        dbo.Sites
WHERE       dbo.Clients.Id IN TVP

Comment: @Michael: yes, of course - it's like a normal table variable inside your procedure!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, SQL Server does not support arrays, however, any Split/Parse function will do

> **EDIT To Include in a WHERE**

```
Declare @String varchar(max) ='1,23,4,3'

Select * 
 From  Clients 
 Where Clients.Id IN ( Select RetVal from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,','))
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

Comment: my purpose is to sent array of integers to stored procedure and then to use this array in where statment in the query.

Comment: @Michael Figured as much.  I often do the same, the results can easily be incorporated into your WHERE or even a JOIN

Comment: @Michael Say your second post.  Consider the updated anwer