# Passing parameters to stored procedure using EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I use sql-server 2012 in my project.

I have stored procedure, I fire and passing parameters to the stored procedure with help of entity framework 6 method called `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

```
 _context.database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_GetRecords", here all params)
```

One of the parameters that I try to sent to stored procedure is list of integers.

I was [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206071/how-do-i-declare-array-of-integers-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure) to create table-valued parameters on sql-server and pass to it array or list.

But don't know how to pass this list or array of integers using `ExecuteSqlCommand` method to table-valued parameter.

Any idea how to pass list or array type inside `ExecuteSqlCommand`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your parameter

```
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
 parameter.ParameterName = "@myData";
 parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
 parameter.TypeName = "dbo.YourCustomTableType";
 parameter.Value = myDataTable;
```

Execute as usual

```
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC SP_GetData @myData", parameter);
```

Comment: reall!?,is it so simple? and I can  pass myData to table-valued parameters ?

Comment: In this row: parameter.Value = myDataTable   what is type of myDataTable?

Comment: DataTable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

We must create NpgsqlParameter and set parametr's name and type

```
        var param1 = new NpgsqlParameter("param1", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Bigint) { Value = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()};

        var param2 = new NpgsqlParameter("param2", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint){ Value = 1}

        return DataSet
            .FromSql("select function_name(@param1, @param2) as \"SomeName\"", parameters: new object[] { param1, param2 })
            .FirstAsync();
    }
```

And that's all