# Concatenate string inside a in clause sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to concatenate a string inside a sql statement. 
I'm using sql server and this is how it looks;

    `declare
     @SchoolID  INT
    ,@Transaction nVarChar(35)
    ,@Reporting nVarChar(35)
    ,@SchoolOf nVarChar(35)
    ,@SchoolYear INT

    ,@Charter Varchar(25)
    ,@Value varchar(max)`

```
SET @SchoolID   = 105           -- HS - 65, MS - 66, ES - 67
SET @TransactionTypeCode = ''   -- '', 'D', 'R'
SET @ReportingLEA = '1'
SET @SchoolOfAttendance = '1' -- HS - 1930056, MS - 6061238, ES - 6010862
SET @SchoolYear =295
SET @Charter = 'ALL'
SET @Value = 
            CASE @Charter
                WHEN 'Los Angeles'
                    THEN 'Los Angeles'
                WHEN'San Diego'
                    THEN 'San Diego'
                WHEN 'Fresno'
                    THEN 'Fresno'                           
                WHEN 'ALL'
                    THEN 'Los Angeles' + ',' +'San Diego'+ ','+'Fresno' --trying to concatenate data to show in the clause IN like charter IN ('Los Angeles','San Diego','Fresno')
            END

 print @Value
```

What i want is that if the user selects 'All'
then the value of 

    `@Value would be: 'Los Angeles' + ',' +'San Diego'+ ','+'Fresno'
    inside the in clause:
    AND gsrf.Charter in (@Value)`

But is not working. 
I believe the in clause doesn't support this kind of concatenation
If run this query and set the variable to 'ALL' then i get this in the print result:

     `Los Angeles,San Diego,Fresno`

But if i run the whole script with this results (without the IN separation) i don't get any data.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a comma-delimited string variable with SQL's IN selector without executing a dynamic statement.

Having said that, you can achieve your goal by changing your @Value type to XML and then querying the XML in place of the comma-delimited string.

So, for exammple:

```
SET @Value = CASE @Charter
    WHEN 'Los Angeles'
        THEN '<cities><city>Los Angeles</city></cities>'
    WHEN'San Diego'
        THEN '<cities><city>San Diego</city></cities>'
    WHEN 'Fresno'
        THEN '<cities><city>Fresno</city></cities>'                           
    WHEN 'ALL'
        THEN '<cities><city>Los Angeles</city><city>San Diego</city><city>Fresno</city></cities>'
END
```

And then use @Value with your IN selector:

```
...AND gsrf.Charter IN (

    SELECT x.f.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(35)' ) AS City FROM @Value.nodes( '//cities/city' ) x( f )

 );
```

Using your "ALL" flag would return the following from @Value:

```
+-------------+
|    City     |
+-------------+
| Los Angeles |
| San Diego   |
| Fresno      |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it, that i couldn't use it like that. 
I was wondering if there was any other chance to do it.

Comment: You're welcome, @rdi0r. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if this resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing with the variables, but I think the logic you want is more like:

```
where (Charter = @Charter or @Charter = 'All')
```

Comment: There's no 'ALL' charter charter must include: Los Angeles, San Diego, Fresno. when the user selects ALL
But in database there no any row like ALL

Comment: @rdi0r . . . That has no comparison of `'All'` to a database column; `'All'` is in the *parameter*, and it would choose all rows (presumably that is the intent).