# SQL Executing store procedure multiple times

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure that will delete from ausers table based on an ID I pass in. If I was to delete multiple users or a range of the IDs, is there a way i can do this?

The IDs are Ints.

Comment: You can pass the start and end id and delete the range, or pass in a comma separated string and use the `IN` clause or pass in a xml formatted list of Ids

Comment: you can (1) pass in a table parameter or a (2) csv of ids and split it in the sp. or (3) pass in a json or xml string of ids

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own versions of stored procedures.)

Comment: Using Microsoft management studio. When seperate the ints with a common i get a "Error converting data type varchar to int." message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: You can use collection or array of int and pass it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create one function which is used to split string and you can pass parameter with separated comma

```
Function
---------------
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO

Store Procedure
----------------------
DECLARE @CustomerID VARCHAR(50) = '1,2,3'

DELETE FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID in (SELECT Item
FROM dbo.SplitString(@CustomerID, ','))
```

Hope this help you :)